# glut - Request for member which is non-class type

Tags: c++, glut

I have a class MouseController. There is a method - update.

```
void MouseController::update(int x, int y) {
this->mX = x;
this->mY = y;

this->diffX = mX  - 650;
this->diffY = mY - 350;

calculateAngle();
}
```

I'm using glut. I want to make glutPassiveMotionFunc and to put that update function.

```
glutPassiveMotionFunc(mouse.update);
```

I get following error :

> D:\projects\cpp\glut\main.cpp|129|error: request for member 'update'
>   in 'mouse', which is of non-class type 'MouseController()'

Comment: How do you define `mouse`? My guess? with `MouseController mouse();` ...

Comment: Yes, 
MouseController mouse();

Answer (score 1):

#### Problem

By defining `mouse`as

```
MouseController mouse();
```

you define a function taking no argument, returning a `MouseController`, called `mouse`. Then, when you call

```
glutPassiveMotionFunc(mouse.update);
```

you try to access the member `update` of the function `mouse`. Hence the error message.

#### Solution

```
MouseController mouse;
```

(would only work if `MouseController::update(int,int)` werestatic, which it is not.)

#### Real solution

```
MouseController mouse;
glutPassiveMotionFunc([&](int x, int y){mouse.update(x, y)});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the signature for `glutPassiveMotionFunc`

```
void glutPassiveMotionFunc(void (*func)(int x, int y));
```

As you can see it takes in a function pointer with two ints as arguments. In C++, you cannot get a pointer to a non-static member function because non-static member functions have the implict first parameter `this` which is unique to each instance of the class.

What you could try is storing a function pointer within MouseController that points to the update function and then pass that into `glutPassiveMotionFunc`

This would give you a way to get a pointer to the function but would still not match the signature of the function pointer needed to be passed in to `glutPassiveMotionFunc`. Look at the other responder's solution for a lambda to do that.

Comment: Would still need `this`.